# Problem with labeling distance after using "Split Line at Points" ArcGIS Pro 3.0

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a county's worth of streams on a map.  I have had to dissolve segments derived from the survey methods before splitting the lines into segments derived from "Split Line at Points".  I've been checking the work using a buffer (see screenshot below) and it appears that I have accomplished the goal.

The next step is to label the individual stream segments with their length.  After a bit of tweaking I can get distance labels between stream confluences but not between the points (they represent fish passage barriers). So, instead of 10 small distances, I get one large distance and that really isn't useful to me.

This does seem to work in a different projection but the client doesn't use that projection so I'm stuck.

I'm still a student and I'm guessing I'm missing something very obvious, so go easy on me.[image]

Comment: From what field are you getting the length values? When you split or dissolve, you generally need to recalculate geographic values such as line length. Are the label values just wrong or are they not showing up?